# Laravel storage disks save file from sftp to local

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want file from `sftp` disk to `local`

I configured my `filesystems.php` and `appserviceprovider.php`

Checking if exist works, but how can i put the remote file to my server?

```
$exists = Storage::disk('sftp')->exists(self::REMOTE_FILE_DEST);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```php
Storage::disk('local')
    ->put('my_local_filename', Storage::disk('sftp')
       ->get(self::REMOTE_FILE_DEST));
```

It should work because we are using togheter:

```php
$contents = Storage::disk('sftp')->get('my_remote_filename');
```

and

```php
Storage::disk('local')->put('my_local_filename', $contents);
```

Comment: Works great, thnx mate!